# global.eval is not able to visit variables in the lexical scope. Does the behavior comply ECMAScript standard?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, closures, eval, interpreter

I have a JavaScript file, `e.js`

```
var global = Function('return this')();

var i = 1;

console.log(eval("100-1"));
console.log(eval("i"));

console.log(global.eval("100-1"));
console.log(global.eval("i"));
```

When I execute it by V8:

```
$ node e.js
99
1
99

undefined:1
i
^
ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/private/tmp/xxxx/e.js:8:20), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/xxxx/e.js:8:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

As a result, `global.eval` works for math operator, but it is unable to visit the variable `i`, while `eval` works for both cases.

Is this behavior a limitation of V8? Or is it the expected behavior according to ECMAScript standard?

Comment: This is spec-compliant behavior; I will try to find a duplicate. See [ES5 15.1.2.1.1 Direct Call to Eval](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1) and step 1 of [10.4.2 Entering Eval Code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is spec-compliant behavior. [ES5 15.1.2.1.1, *Direct Call to Eval*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1), says that one requirement for a call to `eval` to be "direct" is that the reference to `eval` "*has an environment record as its base value*." This means it cannot be a reference done by property access (in which case the owning object would the base value); it must be a "bare" function.

This distinction is critical to step 1 of [10.4.2, *Entering Eval Code*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2):

> 1. If there is no calling context or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then,
>
>    - a. Initialise the execution context as if it was a global execution context using the eval code as C as described in 10.4.1.1.

Thus, an indirect call to `eval` is given a global variable environment, not the local variable environment. Only direct calls get access to the local environment.

This is done for practical implementation reasons, because `eval` can signal to garbage collectors a need to avoid cleaning up any variables. For example, here's a case without `eval`:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 5, b = 6, c = 7;
    return function() { return a; }
}
var func = foo();
alert(func());
```

The function returned by `foo` might access `a` after `foo` terminates, but we can be sure `b` and `c` will never be accessed ever again after `foo` terminates. `b` and `c` can be safely garbage collected, while `a` remains uncollected.

Now a case with `eval`:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 5, b = 6, c = 7;
    return function(exp) { return eval(exp); }
}
var func = foo();
alert(func("b"));
```

It's impossible to generally decide if the `eval` expression `exp` will refer to a given variable, so the garbage collector must *never* collect any of the variables so they are still available for use by the returned function.

In order to decide that `eval` is in use, the parser must be able to reliably recognize a call to `eval`. If the `eval` is presented in an indirect way, like `global["e"+"va"+"l!"[0]]`, the spec says that that `eval`ed code doesn't get access to *any* local variables, thereby avoiding the garbage collection problem.

Comment: But why the same code works on Google Chrome's JavaScript console, while it does not work on Node.js?

Comment: @user955091 It's because `i` is ***not*** a locally-scoped variable in Chrome. Node probably wraps your code in a `(function() { ... })()`. If you wrap it in Google Chrome, you'll see the final call also generates an error.

Comment: What if `eval` is referenced by a local variable of the same name?

Comment: @Melab That will also work. A local variable also uses an "environment record as its base value" same as a global variable: the global environment record is simply an environment record that has no parent record. You could even use `with({ eval: global.eval }) { eval(...); }` since variables created inside `with` scopes also use environment records.