# Do closures keep the whole execution context alive?

Tags: javascript, closures

I understand that closures keep the execution context alive by saving a reference to the executed function.

I'm wondering whether the whole context is saved or only the required parts.
In the former case I need to structure the functions in a way that no memory is wasted. This should be the design goal anyway, but I would like to know if JavaScript takes care of it, too.

Here's a simple example (on the basis of *Single Page Web Applications*, Mikowski/Powell, p. 56):

```
var ctx;
var outer_function = function () {
    var dummy = 'not required for output';
    var output = 'output';
    var inner_function = function () {
        return { output: output };
    }
    return inner_function;
};

ctx = outer_function();
// returns { output: 'output' }
ctx();
```

Is the `dummy` object stored in the closure after the execution of 
`outer_function` even though it is not accessible and won't be used?

Comment: Probably similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/864549/575527

Comment: I guess `dummy` is not stored. I might be wrong but to satisfy a closure, that variable must be referenced in a function. This reference marks it to be kept alive.

Comment: As fas as i know, the whole (engine-internal) Object is stored, that holds all the variables from a particular scope is "stored". But this might be differentiate between the particular JS-Engines.

Comment: @Rajesh I had the same guess, that's why I'm asking. The answer linked by Joseph suggests the opposite. But that was a couple of years ago, maybe something's changed.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000424

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can see that Chrome eliminates unused variables (unless there is a direct `eval` call). Consider the following code ([here's a fiddle to follow along with](https://jsfiddle.net/fzj7ez40/)):

```
var bar = function() {
    var hello = "world";
    var unused = "nope";
    return function(s) { console.log(hello); debugger; return s; };
}
var g = bar();
g(1);
```

`bar` returns a function that has access to the inner variables `hello` and `unused`. The variable `hello` is used inside of the returned function, but `unused` is not. `unused` is entirely inaccessible after the termination of `bar`.

When we run this code with Dev Tools already open (to break on the `debugger` statement), we see:

[image: Dev Tools shows that "Closure" scope only includes <code>hello</code>]

We see that only `hello` has survived in the Closure scope. `unused` has disappeared. We can confirm this by going to the console (while the code is still paused) and seeing that `hello` is defined but accessing `unused` produces a ReferenceError.

This is the fundamental principle of *garbage collection* in action: if a variable becomes completely inaccessible, it should be freed. No one specified that JavaScript engines *must* free completely inaccessible variables, but it's an obvious performance win that is indistinguishable (in language-completeness terms) from not garbage collecting unused variables.

However, direct calls to `eval` *can* access otherwise inaccessible variables. If we modify our returned function to include a direct call to `eval`...

```
var foo = function() {
    var hello = "world";
    var unused = "nope";
    return function(s) { console.log(hello); debugger; return eval(s) };
}
var f = foo();
f(1);
```

We see that all local Closure-scope variables are now preserved:

[image: "Closure" scope includes <code>hello</code>, <code>unused</code>, and <code>arguments</code>]

This is because the environment cannot safely garbage collect any local variables, e.g., for fear that `eval(s)` might evaluate to `unused`.

You might wonder: how can the engine reliably detect the existence of `eval` calls? Couldn't you do something like `window["ev"+"al"](s)` instead, in a way that the engine can't reliable detect? The answer is that such an "indirect" `eval` call does not have access to closure-scope variables and executes in the global scope. Only direct calls that use the identifier `eval` as part of a function call can access local variables, and that's easy to detect.

If you're interested in learning more about direct `eval` calls, see my answer on *[global.eval is not able to visit variables in the lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31460043/710446)*.

Incidentally, this is one of the main performance-based reasons why "`eval` is evil". The presence of a single direct call to `eval` in your code prevents the entire closure from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Re-reading this years later and having much more experience with JS in the meanwhile I need to comment: **This is an excellent answer!** Thanks for your effort.